# How to retrieve the latest record when a time interval is given?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fetch the latest record for a given data set when a product is selected. Each record has prices that are valid for different time intervals. I need to fetch the price for each record that is most recent For instance:

```
product name           price    from_date    to_date
snickers original      5.99     1/1/2017     2/2/2017
snickers original      4.67     3/3/2017     4/4/2017
skittles rainbow       2.99     7/7/2016     8/8/2017
skittles rainbow       8.99     9/9/2016     10/10/2017
```

and the desired result should be the name and the price without the date showing to the user. the date should be hidden like so:

```
snickers original     4.67
skittles rainbow      8.99
```

Comment: use TOP 'N' records and  Order by  the date column.

Comment: @RohitPadma that only works for a single item

Comment: @Blorgbeard you can order all the products based on from_date or To_date and then select the TOP N records. That should work. That is my understand correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @RohitPadma you won't necessarily get one record per `product name` with that method, just the top N most recent prices for any items

Comment: @Blorgbeard My bad i though he want to get N top products :( he need it at product level

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WITH TIES` clause in concert with `Row_Number()`, and assuming there are no FUTURE pricing.

```
Select Top 1 with Ties [product name],Price
 from  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By [product name] Order By To_Date Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
product name       price
skittles rainbow    8.99
snickers original   4.67
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `with ties`, I would usually do a subquery and `where rownumber=1`

Comment: @Blorgbeard Discovered the WITH TIES on SO.  LOVE THIS SITE!  I learn something new every day.

Comment: any suggestions on how to hide the date?

Comment: @jayjayreddick Rather than *, just supply [product name],Price

Comment: @jayjayreddick Happy it helped.